# 24k + Toxic Backlink Received through Trackbacks and Pingbacks

Tags: backlinks, disavow-links, spamming

I have recently noticed that I received 24K+ Toxic Backlinks from a single anchor text through trackback and pingbacks.

Infact the Anchor Text doesn't belong to my niche, so it is simply a spam. My rankings also get affected by it.

I've already Disavowed these domains in Google.

I am pretty sure that this trick is done by a specific source.

Is there any method to find and reach out that specific source? It is better that the main source remove the link so I stop getting more spammy links.

Answer (score 1):

Google is smart enough to know the difference. They crunch tons of data, can see patterns -- and have been doing so for years.  Links are a big part of ranking a site; they don't want the results manipulated.

If you want to believe in negative SEO that's totally up to you.  I'm not going to try to convince you otherwise.

My rankings also get affected by it.
==> I think that no. Because Google is now most Advanced.

Not necessary to submit to Google Disavow. But not harmful in any way that you already submitted.  Google ignores these links.

Better to go through this:

Check Your Site's Search Performance: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34444?hl=en